# In SQL Query records is coming double

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT dbo.productsnrwmtrls.item_Name,
                dbo.estimatesdtls.estm_Id        AS invc_Id,
                dbo.estimatesdtls.item_Id,
                dbo.estimatesdtls.estm_Qntydlvrd AS invc_Qnty,
                dbo.estimatesdtls.estm_Itemprice AS invc_Itemprice,
                dbo.estimatesdtls.estm_Lntotl    AS invc_Lntotl,
                dbo.productsnrwmtrls.item_Uom,
                quotationsdtls.quot_itemDesc,
                dbo.estimatesdtls.estm_Qntyordrd
FROM   dbo.estimatesdtls
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.productsnrwmtrls
         ON dbo.estimatesdtls.item_Id = dbo.productsnrwmtrls.item_Id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN estimates
         ON estimates.estm_ID = estimatesdtls.estm_ID
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN quotationsdtls
         ON quotationsdtls.quot_ID = estimates.quot_ID
WHERE  dbo.estimatesdtls.estm_Id = '105'
```

in this query record are coming 4 but it should fetch 2.
I think so wrong in joining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing exactly what your table structure is, it's hard to figure this out. You should also try formatting your SQL to examine the logical structure. I think your problem lies in the fact that you are doing 3 **outer** joins. An outer join selects rows (left or right accordingly) whether they match something or not.

My suggestion is to break the query down into separate queries with temporary tables to see where the duplicates are coming from. Then you'll know where to change an outer join to an inner one. Try this approach:

```
select
  a.item_Name, a.item_uom,
  b.estm_Id, b.estm_Qntydlvrd, b.estm_Itemprice, b.estm_Lntotl
into temp1
from dbo.productsnrwmtrls a left outer join dbo.estimatesdtls
  on (a.item_Id = b.item_Id)

select
  c.item_Name, c.item_uom,
  c.estm_Id, c.estm_Qntydlvrd, c.estm_Itemprice, c.estm_Lntotl
  d.quot_Id
into temp2
from temp1 c left outer join dbo.estimates d
  on (c.estm_ID = d.estm_ID)
```

The third step will be the right outer join which you would place into a table temp3.

Then examine the results of each step and you will know where the extra rows are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an additional condition in WHERE clause or on JOIN statements